# Getting 404 resource found issue while calling office 365 videos rest api (GET) in on premise sitecollection

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013, office365, office365api

Created on one content editor webpart and calling

```
_api/VideoService/Channels('channelId')/Videos
```

using jquery ajax call, getting 404 error. Below is my ajax code

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " (" + err.statusText + ")");
        }
    });
```

Comment: status text is not found

Comment: http://<site>/SitePages/url?callback=jQuery213020131733012385666_1441375274172&_=1441375274173 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)